# Ruby on Rails Google Api Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

So, I'm very new to this. I got a generated json file from my google developer console that holds information like private keys, client id, token stuff, etc.

Now, I'm trying to use the Google Analytics Report V4 api. I put all my code into a concern, and when I run the code I get this error:

```
Google::Apis::AuthorizationError: Unauthorized
```

So I know that I have to authorize my app, but I'm not sure how. I have this json file which appears to have all the information I need to authenticate my app.

After some research, I know that (on the following code) I need to assign analytics.authorization to something, I just don't know to what.

```
analytics = Google::Apis::AnalyticsreportingV4::AnalyticsReportingService.new
analytics.authorization = ???
```

Do you know of any method I'm supposed to call that takes in the location of my json file as a parameter or something that can in turn, authorize my rails app?

Thank you so so much if you can help.

I know there are other questions like this. But they use omniauth with devise I think, and I can't do that. I already have a specific context in which users need to be logged in to my app, so logging in with google wouldn't work in my case. Also, other question/answers that don't involve omniauth and devise are outdated or don't have an accepted answer.

Comment: You need to authenticate your application.  Your missing all the Oauth code.

Comment: @DaImTo Do I get the oauth code from my developer console?

Comment: No you generate it using the client id and privacy codes in the file you have. After requesting permission of the user.

Comment: @DaImTo what? Do you know how I can go about doing that or do you know where I can look to figure out how to do what your describing? All the documentation I'm finding is outdated or doesn't go into detail.

Comment: Sorry i cant help you much i am not a ruby dev. I would suggest Googling.  Google Analtyics api ruby rails there are loads of tutorials.  I am just no judge on which ones work.